# How to translate words from English into Arabic. With this files lib > providers > language.dart

Tags: android, flutter, type-providers

I have the Flutter Android application. I want to translate words into an application, but this method is strange to me. I do not have enough experience in dealing with translation.

[See photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg5jE.jpg)
[See photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esGyg.png)

Can someone help me with a video how to do this.
I searched for an explanation of the video everywhere in the search engines Google and YouTube. But I did not find an explanation of how to translate. The available explanations are for experienced programmers, not for those who want to modify the translation into some words.

This is what someone told me to do, but I couldn't understand anything from it

You can Change plane Text to [[enter   just you need to use correct langPack text, and also You need to add the text inside Translation.

[See photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnTNL.png)

[See photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSeES.png)

I have no one who will help me except you who have experience in this beautiful site helping people to solve their problems.

Comment: Here are the details
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kfrMHax0sagt0aR8Rjx7So45OxcnD5cg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: languages
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NHzrJ4_0wjCFL606dMVArrC8NXIIoQyJ/view?usp=sharing